# How can i use Apache Beam Latest transformation to get the latest timestamp from pcoll?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, batch-processing, apache-beam

Am trying to manage a PCollection that contains (k,v) pairs:

```
user_id, user_catg, user_login_time, user_class1, type_1

1st_user   1st_catg  2017-12-04 22:15:26  cls_1  type_1
2nd_user   1st_catg  2017-01-04 21:14:06  cls_4  type_0 
3rd_user   2nd_catg  2019-06-01 00:55:256  cls_1  None
1st_user   1st_catg  2018-07-02 20:15:26  cls_2  type_1
2nd_user   3rd_catg  2020-01-01 12:16:06  cls_0  type_2 
3rd_user   2nd_catg  2015-06-01 00:55:256  cls_1 type_1
1st_user   1st_catg  2021-07-02 20:15:26  cls_2  type_1
```

My goal is to drop duplicates on "user_id" (let only unique id's) with the latest "user_login_time"
to get the result below:

```
user_id, user_catg, user_login_time, user_class1, type_1

1st_user   1st_catg  2021-07-02 20:15:26  cls_2  type_1
2nd_user   3rd_catg  2020-01-01 12:16:06  cls_0  type_2
3rd_user   2nd_catg  2019-06-01 00:55:256  cls_1  None
```

I used Apache Beam built in Solution "latest" :

```
with beam.Pipeline() as p:
   latest_user_login = (
   p | "read_file" >> ..............
   | "with timestamp" >> beam.Map(lambda row: beam.window.TimestampedValue(
       (row['user_id'], row['user_cat']), to_unix_time(row['user_login_time'])
   ))
   | 'get_latest_element' >> beam.combiners.Latest.PerKey()
   )
```

but unfortunately this transformation can only takes and returs only 2 filelds
row['user_id'], row['user_cat'] But i need to return All fields.

So that's for your talent to propose other solutions if exists.

Comment: Change row['user_cat'] to row and after the Latest add a `Map(lambda x: x[1])`

Answer (score 1):

`TimestampedValue` gets 2 arguments, first one is the value, the second is the timestamp. Right now you set the value to be a tuple `(row['user_id'], row['user_cat'])`. Just set the entire row to be the value:

```
| "with timestamp" >> beam.Map(lambda row: beam.window.TimestampedValue(
       row, to_unix_time(row['user_login_time'])
   ))
```

Or if you use the `user_id` as the key, use a tuple like `(row['user_id'], row)` as the element because Beam will consider the first element of the tuple to be the key.

See mode in the docs https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.28.0/apache_beam.transforms.window.html#apache_beam.transforms.window.TimestampedValue